# all combination of two symbol with nth length

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a solution using only oracle sql query

Input
two static symbol 'A' and 'B'
n - number

Output if N=3 must give all combination using this symbols

AAA
AAB
ABA
BAA
...

Output if N=4 must give all combination using this symbols

AAAA
AAAB
AABA
ABAA
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old style `connect by` hierarchical query

```
with i(s) as
( 
SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL 
)
select replace(s, ' ', '') s
from (
  select SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(s,' ') s, level l
  from i
  connect by level <= 4
) t
where l = 4
```